# How to copy and paste a value using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently required to copy an order ID and then paste it into a search field.

so far i have tried:

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c")); ,
```

However this fails to copy anything and when pasting it pastes what I have copied earlier by myself.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d466q.png)

Comment: Have you selected the text prior to sending CTRL+C?

Comment: @alecxe  I have not what is the best way for selecting the text? Thanks

Comment: @alecxe Hi i tried .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a"),Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"c"));. However this selected everything and not just the text which i needed within the pop up box. Regards Karan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi why are you coping a particular text i.e order id in your case why not to use getText() and keep the order id in the string and then pass it in the sendKeys() it will be simple and easy to done

```
String myOrderText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ypur xpath to order id")).getText();
```

and the use it like below

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody
/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(myOrderText ));
```

Also if it is mandatory to copy and paste then do it like below

Use actions class of selenium to copy the text (order id )

```
// or any locator strategy that you find suitable 
        WebElement locOfOrder = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the order id"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(locOfOrder).doubleClick().build().perform();
// catch here is double click on the text will by default select the text 
// now apply copy command 

driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"c"));
// now apply the command to paste
driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi @SeleniumLearner looks like the first solution seems to be working, will give it a go Thanks

Comment: plz mark it as your answer as this will be my first answer

Comment: How would I get the text of a paragraph instead of a single word? The paragraph is broken into individual elements

Comment: I'd just like to add that the new version is .send_keys()

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a copy and all. All you have to do is use `getText()`.
Try the following code:

```
String mytext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element path")).sendKeys(mytext);
```

Thank you