# Python / Selenium : paste faster in browser

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a script in python to extract and paste 400-500 lines of text from one browser to another. I am using `send_keys()` to put the text content into the text area. It is writing line by line (2 lines / second) which is resulting in a few minutes to complete the operation. Is there any other method in Selenium to write faster (like how we paste manually in 1 second)?

My code

```
<code>

import time
import re
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def init_driver(uname,pwd):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    driver.get("https://ops.stg1.xxxxxyyyxxxx.com/login.jsp")
    box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_username")))
    box.send_keys(uname)
    box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_password")))
    box.send_keys(pwd)
    button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))
    button.click()
    return driver

def copy():
    with open("Tag_input.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            url = line.strip()  
            driver.get(url)
    k=re.findall('\=(\d+)',url)
    print(k[0])
    a=k[0]
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(10)
    PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='messagingMap.PRIMARY_CONTENT.message']")
    PC.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
    PC.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")
    print("Copied Primary content !!")
    for tag in PC:
        varPC = tag.text
        url1 = "http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder"
        driver.get(url1)
        driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        time.sleep(10)

        text_area = driver.find_element_by_id("unclosed-tag-finder-input")
        text_area.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Submit']")
        button.click()

        result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//pre[@id='unclosed-tag-finder-results']")
        res_list = list(result)
        print(res_list)
        op = result.text
        print(op)

        writer = csv.writer(open('Tag_OP.csv','a+'))
        z = zip(k,result)
        print(z)
        writer.writerows(k)
        writer.writerows(result)
        k = k.pop()
        print("List cleared",k[0])          
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(10)
    return driver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver("abdul.salam@xxxyyxxx.com","xxyyxx")
    copy()
    time.sleep(25)
    driver.quit()

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Ctrl+A to select the text, Ctrl+C to copy it, move to new browser Ctrl+A to select all text in your target field (so that you'll replace it), Ctrl+V to paste.  I could imagine that it may be faster, but I haven't done any benchmarking myself.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840886/how-to-copy-and-paste-a-value-using-selenium) popped right up when I did a search.  It has more details, but, for instance, your paste would look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("unclosed-tag-finder-input").sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"));
```

Comment: Explored the question u referred and did some research and found this (Keys.CONTROL,"c") but it didnt work for me..

Comment: ok...how did it not work?  we can't help you unless you give us more information.

Comment: It is showing indentation error when I use (Keys.CONTROL,"c").. I am using python 3.5 version in windows 7 professional..

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code.  an indentation error indicates a simple formatting problem in your code.

Comment: When I use **driver.find_element_by_xpath** I am getting error [list object has no attribute send_keys]. so when I change my code to **driver.find_elements_by_xpath** I am getting error [WebElement object is not iterable]

Comment: So, have we moved beyond the original question?  you don't mention which line(s) report these problems you just mentioned, but I do see a problem with the code as it is right now.  "PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(..." will return a list of elements, so you can't call PC.send_keys() there.  (it will report list object has no attribute send_keys).  You need to look at the code over there very carefully...you're probably missing a step between there and when you do "for tag in PC:"